# Missing First Open Event in GTM through Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-tag-manager

We've implemented GTM through Firebase on Android according to the latest recommended method from Google, and though we see first_open Events in Firebase, they are not present as built-in Triggers in GTM. The same setup on iOS works perfectly.
Anyone knows what could be the missing point? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this scenario - tracking first_open with GTM - is not supported on Android. You can see which events are supported here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7035192?hl=en

Take a look at the section "Automatically collected events available in Tag Manager for Android and iOS". Surprisingly, first_open is supported on iOS, but not on Android, which explains you situation.

Answer (score -4):

Try to use a custom event like `first_open` instead of using the built-in triggers.